# Data not being exporting to CSV file in python

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am new in python. In my python script I want to export data to CSV file. What i did i have created a number.csv file in the folder where my python script is. I am using python 3.6.6. I have tried too many examples, but none of is working. Here is my code :

```
import csv

nms = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
with open('number.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in nms:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You haven't given many details on what the problem is.  That code should work and write a new csv (well, except for the extra newlines introduced because you didn't use `newline=''` in the `open`) containing two rows of data.  What happens instead for you?

Comment: working fine with me

Answer (score 2):

Code is working fine, nothing wrong in the code. The problem is I was looking the csv file where my python python script file is, but the csv file is generating in the current user's folder.